# How do I delete the first char of next line only?

Tags: substitute

On text like this

```
#Comment
#comment
....

#comment
#Comment
```

I want to delete the #

but only on next line,so become..

```
#Comment
comment
....

#comment
Comment
```

So far I do it with sed like this:

```
sed '/^\#/{n;s/^\#comment/comment/;}'
```

However how can I do it with vim?

Comment: You only care about pairs of lines? Not, for example, removing `#` from 2nd and 3rd lines if you have three lines in a row starting with `#`? Then try `:%s/^\(^#.*\n\)#\(.*\)/\1\2/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Vim:

```
:g/^#/norm j0x
```

which runs `norm j0x` for each line starting with `#`, and `j0x` in normal mode moves down one line and removes the first character.